# Simple Rails App - Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, redis, rubygems

I'm learning how to build a simple rails app and I'm running into some problems getting JQuery to load in the app. I'm getting a console error of "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" but I'm unsure why it isn't working. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I feel like I might be missing some js files, because when I spun up the rails app, there wasn't a "javascripts" directory in my assets and I had to manually create one - not sure if that's normal or not.

Here's a link to my repo as well: https://github.com/scottlandes1217/Hubbubb

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require popper
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hubbubb</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <%= render partial: 'shared/navigation_bar' %>
          <div class="my-3">
            <%= yield %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

forum_channel.js

```
$(function() {
  $('[data-channel-subscribe="room"]').each(function(index, element) {
    var $element = $(element),
        room_id = $element.data('room-id')
        messageTemplate = $('[data-role="message-template"]');

    $element.animate({ scrollTop: $element.prop("scrollHeight")}, 1000)        

    App.cable.subscriptions.create(
      {
        channel: "ForumChannel",
        forun: forum_id
      },
      {
        received: function(data) {
          var content = messageTemplate.children().clone(true, true);
          content.find('[data-role="user-avatar"]').attr('src', data.user_avatar_url);
          content.find('[data-role="message-text"]').text(data.message);
          content.find('[data-role="message-date"]').text(data.updated_at);
          $element.append(content);
          $element.animate({ scrollTop: $element.prop("scrollHeight")}, 1000);
        }
      }
    );
  });
});
```

Thanks again!

Comment: your `application.js` seems to be just a bunch of comments ... how is jquery being loaded? how is your `forum_channel.js` being loaded? is `forum_channel.js` loaded AFTER jquery is loaded?

Comment: Can you check the browser's source view, specifically the included <script>s?

Comment: @JaromandaX I believe that's how the application.js works, but I did attempt to uncomment them out and I'm getting the same results.

Comment: oh, right ... rails ...

Comment: @ChrisG Here's a screencast of my console view and any assets it's loading. I'm not seeing any Jquery at all https://www.screencast.com/t/bE64O6z3NU

Comment: The cause of the error is simple: jQuery is either not included at all, or below your script instead of above. Press Ctrl+U and check the `<head>` section; does it contain a bunch of `<script>`s with working `src`s?

Comment: @ChrisG - You're correct, I'm not seeing jQuery at all in the page source, any suggestions on how to get it to load? I have the gem installed.

Comment: @JaromandaX those comments are directives to Sprockets which is a preprocessor. In development it creates a bunch of script tags for each file and in production it concatenates the whole thing into a single file.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? You're using the old assets pipeline but "there wasn't a "javascripts" directory in my assets and I had to manually create one - not sure if that's normal or not." leads me to believe that you are using Rails 6. Rails 6 uses webpacker instead for javascript. You would install jquery through Yarn instead of a gem and include it in your  `app/javascripts/packs/application.js`.

Comment: Webpack also won't expose jQuery as a global. You either get with the program and use ES6 import directives `import $ from "jquery";` or use [ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/) if you're working with legacy code that relies on globals.

Comment: Your app works for me as is - the only thing I needed to do was add "mini_racer" to the gem file. bundle install and rails server s I was up and running with bootstrap and jquery both working :/ sounds like something up with your setup

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's help - It does look like I needed to install jQuery through a webpack using yarn. A lot of the learning documentation that I was using didn't mention anything like this at all. After installing Jquery the right way and adding my files to the correct directory, jQuery seems to be loading now. I am now running into a separate issue, but I'll post a separate question.

Thanks again, everyone!